# Using variables in commands VBscript

Tags: internet-explorer, variables, vbscript, concatenation

*I have the following code :*

```
objIE.Document.All.a_l_1.click
```

*But I want to do something like this :*

```
objIE.Document.All. & some_var & .click
```

Comment: try objIE.Document.All[some-var].click

Answer (score 2):

You can access the elements of the `document.all` collection by name, e.g.:

```
document.all("a_l_1").click
```

So there is no need for either `Execute` or `Eval()`.

**Update:**

This .HTA:

```
<html>
 <!-- !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595716/using-variables-in-commands-vbscript
 -->
 <head>
  <title>VariableDemo</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="VariableDemo"
  >
  <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
   Sub AClick()
     Report document.all.bttA
     Dim sBtt
     For Each sBtt In Array("bttB", "bttC")
         document.all(sBtt).click
     Next
   End Sub
   Sub XClick(bttX)
     Report bttX
   End Sub
   Sub Report(bttX)
     document.all("txtA").innerText = bttX.innerText & ": " & Now() & vbCrLf & document.all("txtA").innerText
   End Sub
  </SCRIPT>
 </head>
  <body>
   <form>
    <button id="bttA" onclick="AClick">A</button>
    <button id="bttB" onclick="XClick Me">B</button>
    <button id="bttC" onclick="XClick Me">C</button>
    <br />
    <textarea id="txtA" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: 'output']

demonstrates that

```
Report document.all.bttA                - access via named property

document.all("txtA").innerText = ...    - access via string literal

For Each sBtt In Array("bttB", "bttC")  - access via variable
    document.all(sBtt).click
```

all 'work', if the phase of the moon does not interfere.

Comment: I can do that, but i want to use a variable instead of a string. But for some reason, it doesn't work.

Comment: @yuknow - please see update; you must provide more info to hunt down this strange reason.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took with this answer. I should have been more clear with what I needed. I figured it out though, i just used this:           dim isID | isID = 1 | do while isID < 5 | isID=isID + 1 | objIE.document.all("a_1_" & isID) | loop

Answer (score 0):

[Eval](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/eval.html) is what you want. It allows you to evaluate VBScript in string form, which then of course allows you to create that string however you wish.  For example:

```
Dim myElement, evalResult
myElement = "a_l_1"
evalResult = Eval("objIE.Document.All." & myElement & ".click")
```

Comment: DO you mean something like this:                                   Eval(objIE.Document.All.[clicker].click)